# query page(web services in crmod) java code reading from excel !! skip value not found

Tags: java, excel, web-services, search, crm

I have written a code in java for web services of crm on demand. The code reads the 1st column  (id) from excel and queries it in the crm and inserts the values accordingly. If the 'id' is found it inserts the other values, but when the 'id' is not found in the crm the code is terminated with error message. I want the code to query for a record and if found insert the other values, but if the record is not found it should skip that record and query for the next id without it being terminated in between.

Please help...

and also how to skip cells with no value(null)??

Comment: Please show us what you have done already. It is unclear what you are asking, and in particular what library, if any, you are using to interface with Excel.

Comment: The code is in java and I somehow cant post it here according to the code format. How else can i show the code??

Comment: Does [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) help you work out how to format your text?

Comment: Thanks alot... that helped alot... i have posted the code.. please take a look and help me if possible...

Answer (score 0):

```
import crmondemand.ws.account.AccountWS_AccountInsertChild_Input;
import crmondemand.ws.account.AccountWS_AccountInsertChild_Output;
import crmondemand.ws.account.AccountWS_AccountUpdate_Input;
import crmondemand.ws.account.AccountWS_AccountUpdate_Output;
import crmondemand.ws.account.Default_BindingStub;
import crmondemand.xml.account.Account;
import crmondemand.xml.account.RelatedAccount;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

import org.apache.axis.AxisProperties;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class accrel1 {

private String inputFile;
public static int length;

public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
    this.inputFile = inputFile;
}
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(accrel1.class);


public static URL reauthentication(Properties properties) throws MalformedURLException     {

    // System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "172.17.24.24");
    // System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8003");
    //System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "145.247.13.164");
    // System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3128");

    // System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\ProgramFiles\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_31\\jre\\lib\\cacerts");
    System.out.println("Loggin In");
    String jsessionid_full =
        logon("https://secure-ausomxapa.crmondemand.com/Services/Integration",
              "################", "##########", properties);
    System.out.println("Connecting to CRM..." + jsessionid_full);
    String jsessionid = getSessionId(jsessionid_full);
    System.out.println("JSessionid: " + jsessionid);
    String endpoint =
        "https://secure-ausomxapa.crmondemand.com/Services/Integration" +
        ";jsessionid=" + jsessionid;
    URL urlAddr = new java.net.URL(endpoint);
    System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
    return urlAddr;


}

public static void urlqueryWS1(URL urlAddr, List cellDataList,
                               Properties properties) throws RemoteException,
                                                             ServiceException,
                                                             MalformedURLException {



    AxisProperties.setProperty("https.proxyHost",
                               properties.getProperty("proxyhost"));
    AxisProperties.setProperty("https.proxyPort",
                               properties.getProperty("proxyport"));
    // AxisProperties.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "secure-ausomxapa.crmondemand.com");

    crmondemand.ws.account.AccountWS_AccountQueryPage_Input accountlist =
        new crmondemand.ws.account.AccountWS_AccountQueryPage_Input();
    crmondemand.ws.account.AccountWS_AccountQueryPage_Output outlist =
        new crmondemand.ws.account.AccountWS_AccountQueryPage_Output();
    crmondemand.xml.account.Account[] accounts =
        new crmondemand.xml.account.Account[1];
    crmondemand.xml.account.Account account =
        new crmondemand.xml.account.Account();

    String stringCellValue[] = new String[6000];
    int k = 0;
    int flag = 0, notflag = 0, noparentflag = 0;
    System.out.println("CellDatasize:" + cellDataList.size());
    for (int i = 1; i < cellDataList.size(); i++) {

        crmondemand.ws.account.Account service =
            new crmondemand.ws.account.AccountLocator();
        Default_BindingStub stub =
            (Default_BindingStub)service.getDefault(urlAddr);

        List cellTempList = (List)cellDataList.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < cellTempList.size(); j++) {
            HSSFCell hssfCell = (HSSFCell)cellTempList.get(j);
            //System.out.println("Cell Type:" + i + "," + j + "  " +  hssfCell.getCellType());
            if (hssfCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                stringCellValue[j] = hssfCell.getStringCellValue();
                // logger.info(i + "," + j + "\t" + stringCellValue[j] + "\t");
            } else if (hssfCell.getCellType() ==
                       HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(hssfCell)) {
                    System.out.println(hssfCell.getDateCellValue());
                    Date date = new Date();
                    date = hssfCell.getDateCellValue();
                    SimpleDateFormat df =
                        new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    stringCellValue[j] = df.format(date);

                } else {

                    stringCellValue[j] = new BigDecimal(hssfCell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString(); 
                    //logger.info("Number"+i+","+j+ "\t"+stringCellValue[j] + "\t");
                }


            }
        }


        AccountWS_AccountInsertChild_Input child =
            new AccountWS_AccountInsertChild_Input();
        AccountWS_AccountInsertChild_Output childs =
            new AccountWS_AccountInsertChild_Output();


        crmondemand.xml.account.Account[] accrels =
            new crmondemand.xml.account.Account[1];
        crmondemand.xml.account.Account accrel =
            new crmondemand.xml.account.Account();


        RelatedAccount[] relaccounts = new RelatedAccount[1];
        RelatedAccount relaccount = new RelatedAccount();
        logger.info("Inserting " + i + "Record: "+stringCellValue[0]);

        relaccount.setRelationshipRole(stringCellValue[1]);
        relaccount.setRelatedAccountId(stringCellValue[2]);
        relaccount.setStartDate(stringCellValue[6]);
        relaccount.setEndDate(stringCellValue[7]);
        relaccount.setReverseRelationshipRole(stringCellValue[3]);
        relaccount.setComments(stringCellValue[4]);
        relaccount.setRelationshipStatus(stringCellValue[5]);


        relaccounts[0] = relaccount;

        accrel.setAccountId(stringCellValue[0]); //JDE Account ID
        accrel.setListOfRelatedAccount(relaccounts);

        accrels[0] = accrel;

        child.setListOfAccount(accrels);


        try {
            childs = stub.accountInsertChild(child);
            logger.info(i + "th Record Inserted");
            ++flag;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Network Error: Re-Authenticating" + e);


            urlAddr = reauthentication(properties);

            stub = (Default_BindingStub)service.getDefault(urlAddr);
            childs = stub.accountInsertChild(child);
            logger.info(i + "th Record Inserted in 2nd Attempt");
            ++flag;
        }
//logger.info("Total No. Of Records Processed"+flag);


    }
    logger.info("Total No. Of Records Processed"+flag);
}

private void readExcelFile(URL urlAddr, String fileName,
                           Properties properties) throws ServiceException,
                                                         RemoteException,
                                                         MalformedURLException {
    System.out.println("Reading Excel File");
    /**
* Create a new instance for cellDataList
*/
    List cellDataList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        /**
* Create a new instance for FileInputStream class
*/
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        /**
* Create a new instance for POIFSFileSystem class
*/
        POIFSFileSystem fsFileSystem =
            new POIFSFileSystem(fileInputStream);

        /*
* Create a new instance for HSSFWorkBook Class
*/
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsFileSystem);
        HSSFSheet hssfSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

        /**
* Iterate the rows and cells of the spreadsheet
* to get all the datas.
*/
        Iterator rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow hssfRow = (HSSFRow)rowIterator.next();
            Iterator iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
            List cellTempList = new ArrayList();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                HSSFCell hssfCell = (HSSFCell)iterator.next();
                cellTempList.add(hssfCell);

            }
            cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /**
* Call the printToConsole method to print the cell data in the
* console.
*/
    urlqueryWS1(urlAddr, cellDataList, properties);

}



private static String logon(String wsLocation, String userName,
                            String password, Properties properties) {
    String sessionString = "FAIL";
    int port =
        Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("proxyport")); //Converting String Port Number to Integer.
    try {
        Proxy proxy =
            new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(properties.getProperty("proxyhost"),
                                                             port));
        // create an HTTPS connection to the On Demand webservices
        URL wsURL = new URL(wsLocation + "?command=login");
        HttpURLConnection wsConnection =
            (HttpURLConnection)wsURL.openConnection(proxy);
        // we don't want any caching to occur
        wsConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        // we want to send data to the server
        // wsConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        // set some http headers to indicate the username and passwod we are using to logon
        wsConnection.setRequestProperty("UserName", userName);
        wsConnection.setRequestProperty("Password", password);
        wsConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // see if we got a successful response
        if (wsConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // get the session id from the cookie setting
            sessionString = getCookieFromHeaders(wsConnection);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Logon Exception generated :: " + e);
    }
    return sessionString;
}

private static String getCookieFromHeaders(HttpURLConnection wsConnection) {
    // debug code - display all the returned headers
    String headerName;
    String headerValue = "FAIL";
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        headerName = wsConnection.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
        if (headerName != null && headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
            // found the Set-Cookie header (code assumes only one cookie is being set)
            headerValue = wsConnection.getHeaderField(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    // return the header value (FAIL string for not found)
    return headerValue;
}

private static String getSessionId(String cookie) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(cookie, ";");
    String jsessionid = st.nextToken();
    st = new StringTokenizer(jsessionid, "=");
    st.nextToken();

    return st.nextToken();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
                                              ServiceException {

    String jsessionid, jsessionid_full;
    String endpoint;


    AxisProperties.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "172.25.9.240");
    AxisProperties.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "2006");

    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "172.25.9.240");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "2006");

    // System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "145.247.13.164");
    // System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3128");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\10608011\\Documents\\Account_Config.properties")); //Windows Path

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Oracle\\Middleware3\\jdk160_24\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
    System.out.println("Logging In");
    jsessionid_full =
            logon("https://secure-ausomxapa.crmondemand.com/Services/Integration",
                  "############", "###########", properties);
    System.out.println("Establishing " + jsessionid_full);
    jsessionid = getSessionId(jsessionid_full);
    System.out.println("Jsessionid: " + jsessionid);
    endpoint =
            "https://secure-ausomxapa.crmondemand.com/Services/Integration" +
            ";jsessionid=" + jsessionid;
    URL urlAddr = new java.net.URL(endpoint);


    String fileName =
        "D:" + File.separator + "Test2.xls"; // Windows Path
    // String fileName =File.separator + "u01"+File.separator +"CRM_DEV"+File.separator +
    //                "sofwaredepot"+File.separator +"PALS_200_11Feb2013.xls";               //Linux Path /u01/CRM_DEV/softwaredepot

    // String fileName="PALS_200_11Feb2013.xls";
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.info("Start Time:" + start);
    new accrel1().readExcelFile(urlAddr, fileName, properties);
    final long durationInMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Time(Min) for Data Upload: " +
                       durationInMilliseconds / 60000 + "mins.");
    logger.info("Duration for Data Upload: " +
                durationInMilliseconds / 60000 + "mins.");


}
}
```

Comment: This is the code I have... it works fine when it finds an existing ID but it exits as soon as the ID isnt found... i want it to skip the ID which is not found and move to the next ID and search that... Please help @KenY-N....